# TextBox Control Not Updating .Text property

Tags: c#, uwp

Can anyone shed light on this issue?

I have a bunch of controls creating in a class

```
public static TextBox uname = new TextBox { PlaceholderText = "Username", Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0), Text = MainPage.UNAME };
```

When I call the database to update the UNAME field on the mainpage, it does and I can print the new value. However, The textBox that is shown above which resides in a different class does not update to the new value.

I've tried initializing this textbox after the database gets the values but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Having `static` control instances is a bad idea - what if you want to display multiple instances of your UI?

Comment: Also your field is `public` but not `readonly`. Consider converting it to an auto-property.

Comment: Thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out a way around it.

I changed this line:

```
public static TextBox uname = new TextBox { PlaceholderText = "Username", Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0), Text = MainPage.UNAME };
```

To this:

```
public static TextBox uname = new TextBox { PlaceholderText = "Username", Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0) };
```

Then put all my Text assignments in the initialization method.

ex. , uname.Text = MainPage.UNAME

Then.. I called the init after the DB call and poof it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The uname TextBox is instantiated and assigned when your Page is created. Although you call the database to update the `MainPage.UNAME` but you have not changed the  pointer content of `uname.Text`. The easy way you can set `uname.Text` directly like `uname.Text = MainPage.UNAME`.

You can also use xaml data Binding like code behind.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public ViewModel viewModel { get; set; }      
 public MainPage()
 {          
     this.InitializeComponent();
     this.viewModel = this.DataContext as ViewModel;

 }

 private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {   
     viewModel.Uname = MainPage.UNAME;
 }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<TextBox
    Margin="0,0,5,0"
    PlaceholderText="User Name"
    Text="{Binding Path=Uname}" />
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private string uname;
public string Uname
{
    get
    {
        return uname;
    }

    set
    {
        uname = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (eventHandler != null)
    {
        eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: downvote... not using xaml for this. boxes are created in code.